# Javascript: Awaiting a promise without using async await

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am returning a Promise in `getInfo()`.

```
function getInfo() {
    return axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.userName
    }
}
```

Assuming that request can take a few seconds, I can wait for it with `await` by using async/await.

```
async function test() {
   let userName = await getInfo();
   // waiting for userName in order to do other stuff below
   // other stuff
}
```

if I didn't use async/await though, how would this just be done with Promises?  Would this be the valid way to do it?

```
   function test() {
       let userName;
       getInfo().then(data => {
              userName = data;
       })
       // other stuff that depends on userName value
   }
```

Comment: All of the code that needs to use `userName` must be inside the `then`.

Comment: Not really, the `other stuff that depends ..` must be in a `then` too.

Comment: ^^ (You both mean the same thing)